# What are best practices for maintaining a Mysql database schema in a cross platform way?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, jooq

We have two software stacks, Ruby on Rails and Java, that share a single Mysql database.  We're using the Jooq Java database abstraction layer, which works by reading an existing database schema and generating code.

We have been relying on Rails migrations to keep track of schema changes, but our Java developers are unfamiliar with this, and our Rails devs have had to dig us out of problems more than once.  It's also a rather cumbersome process, making a schema change can take 5-10 minutes, whereas it would take seconds if modifying the schema directly through a tool like MySql Workbench.

It would be preferable to have a solution for modifying our DB schema that wasn't tied to Rails, can anyone recommend a suitable approach?

Comment: Check out Liquibase or Flyway. And **never** do changes directly through a SQL tool. It is too much trouble in the long run.

Comment: [dbv (database version control)](https://github.com/victorstanciu/dbv) might be a good fit.

Comment: Did you consider to build an abstraction layer on the database by creating stored procedures for all database operations and have both the java and the RoR code interact with the database only through those procedures? That way you could change the database schema without breaking any code, for neither RoR nor Java.

Comment: [RedGate SQL Source Control](http://red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/) works well.  I wrote a job to run their SQL Compare every hour.  That detects differences between source control and the database.  So that they can't get out of sync.

Comment: Just a note: the migrations are not tied to Rails, there's a library called ActiveRecord that Rails uses under the hood.. I would not recommend that but you *could* actually extract the database migrations to a separate project.

Comment: Also wouldn't it be possible to choose a stack that will talk to the database and provide an API to the other? I guess you have reasons why it's this way but still...

Comment: @Jiří We could do that, then we'd need to proxy every operation that one of the stacks might need to do on the database through the other stack - which seems like a lot of work for not much gain.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you could take a look at [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org). It's a Java-based tool, but as I understand it would suit some of your requirements. Using that tool you are able to express the database content (both structure and data), then run such a tool against a running database and the tool will tell you what changes are missing and will apply them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however the fact that the migrations must be expressed in XML is probably a dealbreaker for me, I really hate it when people use XML where other representations make far more sense (in this case isn't SQL the obvious language in which to represent migrations?).  Again, not criticizing you - just venting :-)

Comment: @sanity: then do checkout Flyway. It is more or less the same as Liquibase but doesn't use XML. Although I do think XML is a good choice here, you can validate the correctness of the migrations before running them and Liquibase can handle multiple target DBMS better.

Comment: Thanks, Flyway does indeed look very interesting.  We'll need to agree to disagree about XML.  I don't think it should be used for anything other than text markup, which is the one thing it was actually designed to do.  I'm not a fan of whoever decided that it would make a good generic data representation language :-)

Comment: XML: I see. Liquibase can be used in two different approaches. Both require XML, while the first one makes you express everything in XML-like way, the other way makes you just use simple entries like `<sqlFile path=...>` and then you put your SQL statements. So it seems like there's a chance to avoid heavy XML.

Comment: We had Liquidbase in one of our projects. I haven't been touching that a lot, but at that point I had an experience with RoR already and I had a feeling LB is way behind RoR Migrations. It's defined in XML and it don't determine current version of DB (at least it wasn't in our setup). 
My feeling is that RoR migrations DSL is very easy to understand for non-Ruby guys; and with little practice it's easy to write as well. 
On my current project I'm using RoR and I'm happy :)
So I would propose to topic starter to create some guide for Java guys and continue with RoR